# Cookie without Secure flag and HttpOnly flag set

Tags: php, html, cookies

Recently a scan was run on one of our applications and it returned the following 1 security threats:

1.Cookies NotMarked As Secure::Cookie without Secure flag set

2.Cookie without HttpOnly flag set::Cookiewithout HttpOnly flag set

```
$this->cache_ptr = new CACHE($_COOKIE["sess"], 0, 0);
```

CACHE is an user built library that uses Sessions etc.

I am not sure about the right syntax to mark the cookie secure and set the cookie with HttpOnly flag. Also, this is a legacy application running in php 4.
Can someone please help me with this or point me to a resource?

EDIT:
I implemented Sven's recommendation. Is there a way I can test the secure functionality?

Also,Since I am using php4(which will have to be updated eventaully)
I cannot use httponly in the setcookie function.
So does that mean,I need to add the following line before setcookie function?

```
header("Set-Cookie: hidden=value; httpOnly");
```

will it intefere with my setcookie function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `setcookie()`. read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).  Set the sixth parameter to true to make the cookie secure.

Comment: httponly is another parameter that you can set with `setcookie()`

Comment: Also the php version is less than 5 and it does not support httponly paarameter. is there a way without upgrading the php version for now.

Comment: If you dont' have that version, you will have to set the cookie manually with the header function:  `header( "Set-Cookie: name=value; httpOnly" );`

Answer (score 1):

The code you are showing does not set the cookie. It might trigger setting a cookie, but essentially you must look at the `CACHE` class and see what's going on there.

You are looking for function calls of `setcookie()`, and if not found, for `header('Set-Cookie...')`.

You'll have to change setcookie() to include all the default values for the optional parameters, until at the end you set the last two to true for secure and httponly.

Have a look at the manual: https://www.php.net/setcookie

Comment: thanks Landen and sven. Is there a way I can test to see if it's secure and http only? I dont have the security scan software that was used to run initially.

Comment: Firebug will show you the result. Additionally checking the `Set-Cookie` response header from the server will do as well.

Comment: can I also add secure to it function: header( "Set-Cookie: name=value; httpOnly secure" );